# jquery mobile style not applying on regular select

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

There are three frames, in second frame i have loaded all the required js and css files, but still select is not stylised. I added `$('.change-theme-wrapper').trigger('create');` It did styled but the select was not opening. And its giving TypeError: r[0] is undefined. Same html code works in other frame but not in this frame. js libraries are loaded in head and other js libraries loaded in body. Please help me.

HTML:

```
<div class="change-theme-wrapper" data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                        <select data-theme="b" id="change_theme" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" data-icon="gear">
                            <option data-placeholder="true" value="">Change Theme</option>
                            <option value="b">Blue</option>
                            <option value="a">Black</option>
                            <option value="c">Silver</option>
                            <option value="d">Plain White</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Javascript Version:

jquery-min v1.8.2
jquery-mobile v1.2.0

Comment: You need to show us code and markup, and tell us which versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile you are using. If you can also reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle you will probably get an even quicker response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the select menu after initializing it. Use this code after executing trigger. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
$('#change_theme').selectmenu('refresh');
```